# CSRF validation does not work on Django using HTTPS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, ibm-cloud, django-csrf

I am developing an application which the frontend is an AngularJS API that makes requests to the backend API developed  in Django Rest Framework.

```
The frontend is on the domain: https://front.bluemix.net
And my backend is on the domain: https://back.bluemix.net
```

I am having problems making requests from the frontend API to the backend API. The error is this:

```
Error: CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - https://front.bluemix.net does not match any trusted origins.
```

I am using CORS and I have already included the following lines in my settings.py in the Django backend API:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.bluemix.net/']

CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True

CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'bluemix.net'

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://front.bluemix.net/',
    'front.bluemix.net',
    'bluemix.net',
)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/  ?

Comment: Yes I did! The error is the same...

Comment: Maybe your version of django is not supported. Try this fork https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Reason given for failure: Origin checking failed does not match any trusted origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285834/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-reason-given-for-fail)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

##### Django 4.0 and above

For Django 4.0 and above, `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` must include [scheme and host](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins), e.g.:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.bluemix.net']
```

##### Django 3.2 and lower

For Django 3.2 and lower, `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` must contain [only the hostname](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins), without a scheme:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['front.bluemix.net']
```

You probably also need to put something in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`...

Comment: Thanks, the issue was with the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS. Now it works like a charm :)

Comment: Thank you my friend. I had the same issue and it's solved now!!

Comment: Public utility: you may want to specify the web server port, so use `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['localhost:8080']`

Comment: Thank you!!!!! These CORS issues are driving me insane

Comment: Note that in Django 4.0 it changed. Now scheme is required. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0

Comment: How about i want to allow csrf to the whole hosts not only to one in my LAN network?

Comment: So what.  The trailing / was the problem? this answer is not clear.

Comment: @java-addict301 yes, the trailing slash will cause a CSRF failure.

Comment: it still doesn't work for me

Comment: You saved my life today!

Answer (score 16):

If you are running Django 4.x, you need to change the syntax to include the schema as part of the value.

`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['front.bluemix.net']`
to
`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.bluemix.net']`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/4.0/#format-change

Answer (score 13):

I was also facing this issue. Ensure that the domain name does not contain the trailing slash. Instead of

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.bluemix.net/']
```

Change it to

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.bluemix.net']
```

Comment: Thanks so much.
This stupidity ate us many hours.

Comment: this advice is pure gold

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who follows this, if you have set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True`, then you don't need to set the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` variable anymore, as you are allowing every host already.

**SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM - it might help somebody**

the problem we had was a peculiar one, we have a Client application sending requests using **TokenAuthentication** to another application, a CRM built using Django Admin and therefore using **SessionAuthentication**. When we opened the Django Admin application, the **SessionMiddleware** was creating automatically a **session_id** cookie for that domain. When opening the Client application and trying to perform a request, we got the following error:

```
Error: CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - https://domainofthedjangoadminapp.com does not match any trusted origins.
```

That was only because the **session_id** cookie was already set in the browser and therefore, the request was made using **SessionAuthentication** instead of **TokenAuthentication** and failing.

Removing the cookie was obviously fixing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

According to this documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes

1. install cors-header by: doing
   `pip install django-cors-headers`
2. Add corsheaders to you installed apps

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'MyApp',
   'crispy_forms',
   'corsheaders',
   ]
   ```
3. Add the corsheader Middleware to your middleware

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
   '**corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware**',
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
   ```

4 Set the origin

```
 CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.bluemix.net']
```

Answer (score 5):

### Apr, 2022 Update:

If your **django version** is **"4.x.x"**:

```
python -m django --version

// 4.x.x
```

Then, if the error is as shown below:

> Origin checking failed -  [https://example.com](https://example.com/)  does not match any trusted origins.

Add this code below to **"settings.py"**:

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://example.com']
```

In your case, you got the similar error to above:

> Error: CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - https://front.bluemix.net does not match any trusted origins.

So, you need to add this code to **your "settings.py"**:

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.bluemix.net']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using for example Flexible TLS/SSL Setting in Cloudflare, put following in your Django settings.py:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue can also occur if you have Cloudflare's SSL/TLS encryption mode set to Flexible. Instead of the site actually being served through Https, Cloudflare was modifying the http site and setting SSL on its end. This led to a failure of CSRF mechanism, and I kept seeing this error, whatever my CSRF settings were. Toggling off the setting immediately fixed the error.

Comment: Thanks for this tip - it fixed a CSRF breakage for me!