# wrong behavior of uwsgi and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in django

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have a problem with uwsgi and the CSRF verification. I have set up the domain in my `settings.py` like:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=['https://example.com']
```

and this also works with `python manage.py runserver`, but when I use uwsgi I get the error message:

```
Reason given for failure:

    Referer checking failed - https://example.com/ does not match any trusted origins.
```

It is actually complaining about the exact domain that I have setup in the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` list, how can that be? And why does it work with the django runserver?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841109/csrf-validation-does-not-work-on-django-using-https . It seems you have the same issue.

Comment: thanks, that was actually the problem. I already tested this out but I had a second problem with my environment vars which I passed but then did not check again without https://. Damn, you can post it as answer if you want to