# How to solve CSRF verification faileld?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf, django-4.0

Request aborted.
Help

Reason given for failure:

> Origin checking failed - https://teamsparrowpp-qrgen-production 6a43.up.railway.app does not match any trusted origins.

I have `<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}` on my html.
I have tried adding on settings

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://teamsparrowpp-qrgen-production-6a43.up.railway.app']
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Are your origin and host the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285834/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-reason-given-for-fail).  With the limited information you gave, it looks like this might solve your problem.