# AWSApprunner not able to send email from django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, django-views, amazon-app-runner

When I try to send and email from django running on AWSAppRunner instance, the screen stays loading for a while and then it turns all white. If I open my debugger, I see a 502 network error:
Origin checking failed {My DOMAIN APPEARED HERE } does not match any trusted origins.

I [Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Reason given for failure: Origin checking failed does not match any trusted origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285834/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-reason-given-for-fail) and I added these credentials mentioned in that stack page (CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS,CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST, CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER) and then got this error.
Origin checking failed - null does not match any trusted origins.

I do have the CSFR token on my html  {% csrf_token %}. I know its the email because I comment that send_email function and everything works as expected. I verified the identities (from email and to email) in AWS SES. I  installed SES with pip and added :

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'  AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2' AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'` 
I also have my access key, I was able to send the email using my localhost (My own computer running python manage.py runserver). I allowed all trafic in and out on the security group.

What else can I try ?

```
def nuevaorden_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            nombre = request.POST.get("nombre")
            email = request.POST.get("email")
            telefono = request.POST.get("telefono")
            TipoDeServicio = request.POST.get("TipoDeServicio")
            ServiciosCombinados = request.POST.getlist("ServiciosCombinados")
            FrecuenciaDeServicio = request.POST.get("FrecuenciaDeServicio")
            Description = request.POST.get("Description")
            CiudadOrigen = request.POST.get("CiudadOrigen")
            PaisOrigen = request.POST.get("PaisOrigen")
            CodigoPostalOrigen = request.POST.get("CodigoPostalOrigen")
            CiudadDestino = request.POST.get("CiudadDestino")
            PaisDestino = request.POST.get("PaisDestino")
            CodigoPostalDestino = request.POST.get("CodigoPostalDestino")
            Status = 'Orden Abierta'
            Carrier = 'CorreKaminos'
            
            orden = NuevaOrden(
                nombre=nombre,
                email=email,
                telefono=telefono,
                TipoDeServicio=TipoDeServicio,
                ServiciosCombinados=ServiciosCombinados,
                FrecuenciaDeServicio=FrecuenciaDeServicio,
                Description=Description,
                CiudadOrigen=CiudadOrigen,
                PaisOrigen=PaisOrigen,
                CodigoPostalOrigen=CodigoPostalOrigen,
                CiudadDestino=CiudadDestino,
                PaisDestino=PaisDestino,
                CodigoPostalDestino=CodigoPostalDestino,
                Status=Status,
                Carrier=Carrier
            )

            try:
                orden.save()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            # Save the instance to the database

            try:
                mail_subject = "Nueva orden"
                message = ('Una nueva orden ha sido creada.')
                from_email = "IvanGonzalez@correkaminos.com"  
                to_email = ['carlosugartechea@correkaminos.com']  
                send_mail(mail_subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=False)
                messages.success(request, "La orden se ha creado correctamente.")
                return render(request, "ordenes/ordenregistrada.html")
            except Exception as e:
                # Handle other exceptions (e.g., email sending failure)
                print(e)
                return render(request, "ordenes/nuevaorden.html")
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return render(request, "ordenes/nuevaorden.html")
```

[Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Reason given for failure: Origin checking failed does not match any trusted origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285834/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-reason-given-for-fail)

Comment: I checked my request with the network debugger and I see these values:

From data
csrfmiddlewaretoken: "KbQlpGPGDgh7K4WNwNIRJ3qbJERPcTwFjsT2XE3Bebg7TuxlnNl4XmTw3Kczchsd"

Cookies data
csrftoken JrdRI8o5L59ajALI1aNnotDvugvUay6I

Comment: amazon logs shows this 
2024-02-21T00:56:39.429-06:00 [2024-02-21 06:56:39 +0000] [11] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:17)
 2024-02-21T00:56:39.429-06:00 [2024-02-21 06:56:39 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17)
 2024-02-21T00:56:39.582-06:00 [2024-02-21 06:56:39 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18

Comment: are you using gunicorn?

Comment: @Tanveer I’m using AWS app runner it’s a PAAS. It automatically did all the configs for me.